# Overflow property not respecting padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the below screenshot, overflow is working but it goes right to the end of the container and looks terrible.

Is there a way I can cut it off at a certain point and make it respect the padding? So that the text ends where the padding is instead of the container edge?

[image]

My code for this div specifically is below:

```css
/*Blog Card Styling*/

#blogCardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.blogCard {
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  grid-column: 2;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  align-self: start;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 10em;
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.trendingTab {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  align-self: start;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
}


/*Blog Card Stylnig End*/
```

```html
<div id='blogPostSectionContainer'>

  <div class='blogCard'>

    <h1>First Post</h1>
    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </span></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have the overflow respect the padding in that manner.  To achieve that effect you should use some variations of borders and box shadows.

The easiest solution would just be to make your border transparent, and the width of the padding you want to use, and then use something like box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black; to mimic the 1px border you have in the screenshot.

It seems like overall you are trying to have the text cut off in the style of an "excerpt" for the blog card though.

Combining the original HTML above, the CSS you started with, the border and box-shadow solution above, this is a more complete way of doing it, which also adds the vertical ellipsis for the content overflow:

```css
/*Blog Card Styling*/
#blogCardContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

/* mixin for blog card */
.blogCard {
  background-color: white;
  grid-column: 2;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2em solid transparent;
  padding: 0 2em;
  align-self: start;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  max-height: 14.54em;
}
.blogCard p {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  min-height: 7.2em;
  max-height: 7.2em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.blogCard p:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.blogCard p:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
/*Blog Card Stylnig End*/
```

```html
<div id='blogCardContainer'>
 <div class='blogCard'> 
  <h1>First Post</h1>
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempo. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </span></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

The card mixin is in scss, so you can reference [the codepen](https://codepen.io/times/pen/MRddqQ) I made for this if you want to mess around with it some more to make it fit your design better.  The height for the excerpt and card is based off however many lines you set for the variable $lineCount instead of using the original 10em height you had in your CSS.

Answer (score -3):

Tried to remove some lines and here's what I got:

```css
/* No stylings on the container just .blogPost */
.blogCard {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Since I don't know what it is you want specifically, don't know if it helps